# Control UI visibility on Recycler View item via DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I am learning MVVM with data binding in Android and got stuck on maintaining UI visibility state of items in the recycler view. Each item sell has 2 text view - title(visible) & description(hidden). Onclick of title, I want to show/hide description. To maintain its UI state, I have a boolean field in the POJO (shared with DB as an entity).
OnClick of title, I am trying to set this field. How can I make the change trigger changing the visibility and maintain it during the scroll?

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/Kotlin_Practice/tree/java_version/MVVM_ROOM) for the code and below, the code snippet that I want to work.
Following MVVM architecture with repository to hit network and update DB and observe data via LiveData.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="@{posts.desc}"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="@{(posts.isDescVisible()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            tools:text="This is an answer provided by the creator to test the UI layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:onClick="@{()-> posts.setDescVisible(!posts.isDescVisible())}"
            android:text="@{posts.title}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="This is a question" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="posts"
            type="com.tyagiabhinav.loremipsum.model.db.Posts" />

    </data>

</layout>
```

Comment: Try adding this line to setDescVisible -> **notifyPropertyChanged(BR.descVisible);**

Comment: I tried that by making my Posts class as BaseObservable and setting @Bindable to setter. Did not worked. Please check the repo!

Comment: I didn't see you extending the BaseObservable class in you repo. Please try the answer

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi probably you need to use `BindingAdapter`

Comment: @rahat where and how should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well for me

```
import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;

public class Posts extends BaseObservable {
    private int id;
    private final String title;
    public final String desc;
    private boolean descVisible;

    public Posts(String title, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDescVisible(boolean  descVisible) {
        this.descVisible = descVisible;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.descVisible);
    }
    
    @Bindable
    public boolean isDescVisible() {
        return descVisible;
    }
}
```

And the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="@{posts.desc}"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            ***android:visibility="@{posts.descVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"***
            tools:text="This is an answer provided by the creator to test the UI layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:onClick="@{()-> posts.setDescVisible(!posts.descVisible)}"
            android:text="@{posts.title}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="This is a question" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="posts"
            type="com.tyagiabhinav.loremipsum.model.db.Posts" />

    </data>

</layout>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid  notifyChange(); and use with @Bindable with notifyPropertyChange();

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi Okay, I edited. Make sure your desc variable is public

Comment: It did not worked... My POJO is shared as DB entity.

Comment: I see you've now used notifyChange(). Can you post your POJO with notiyPropertyChanged()? I replicated your project and it worked just fine for me

Comment: Sorry, did not commit the code. Now check.

Comment: I added the xml with a line highlighted in the first text view. You need to fetch the variable name and not the getter method. i.e you should be using **posts.descVisible** instead of **posts.isDescVisible()**